# How to get original HTML back after it was changed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the original heading text to display after it was changed by jQuery, without having to write in both the markup and in the script.

My html starts with:

```
<div class="headings">
<h1>Original Heading</h1>
</div>
```

Then after a user makes their selection, the heading is changed with jQuery:

```
  $('#userSelection').on('click', function() {
    $('.headings h1').html('<h1>New Heading</h1>');
  });
```

Currently I have it set so if a user clicks the reset button, the heading is changed back to the original with jQuery:

```
  $('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {
    $('.headings h1').html('<h1>Original Heading</h1>');
  });
```

Is there a way to get back to the original heading without having to write it out in jQuery, since it's already in the original HTML?

Comment: Why not just hide and show rather than changing the HTML? Or better yet, just change the data itself, and leave the original markup.

Comment: @chris - I have many user selection options and I want to show the value of their selection, so writing out all the options in the markup seems a bit clunky.  I could just make the change with .text()

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tempBucket = '';//temporary bucket to save our original
  
  //if use localstorage can be like this one
  // var tempBucket = localStorage.getItem('original') ?? '';
  
  $('#selectBtn').click(function(){
    tempBucket = $('.headings h1').html();
    //if using localstorage
    //localStorage.setItem('original', $('.headings h1').html());
    $('.headings h1').html('New Headings');
  });
  
  $('#resetBtn').click(function(){
    $('.headings h1').html(tempBucket);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headings">
<h1>Original Heading</h1>
</div>

<button id="selectBtn">select</button>
<button id="resetBtn">reset</button>
```

Hopefully can answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Only way to get it back is to refresh the page, or once again write it back with jQuery.

Comment: ok, so the method I am using sounds like it's correct then.  What about setting the original html in a variable or localStorage etc.? And then calling it later? Just thinking out loud here, not sure if any of those options are any better than my current set up.

Answer (score 0):

Your current method inserts another `<h1>` into the existing `<h1>` which may not be what you're after. This first snippet demonstrates that. The nested `<h1>`'s appears to be what causes the font-size to increase when clicking. Interesting...

```js
$('#userSelection').on('click', function() {
  $('.headings h1').html('<h1>New Heading</h1>');
});

$('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {
  $('.headings h1').html('<h1>Original Heading</h1>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headings">
  <h1>Original Heading</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="userSelection" value="userSelection">
  <input type="button" id="resetBtn" value="resetBtn">
</div>
```

The second snippet shows using `.empty().append()` which does not cause nested `<h1>`'s.

```js
$('#userSelection').on('click', function() {
    $('.headings').empty().append('<h1>New Heading</h1>');
  });


  $('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {
    $('.headings').empty().append('<h1>Original Heading</h1>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headings">
<h1>Original Heading</h1>
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" id="userSelection" value="userSelection">
<input type="button" id="resetBtn" value="resetBtn">
</div>
```